# Ruby Regex to replace all occurrences EXCEPT if an HTML attribute

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to wrap all instances of `%{ ... %}` with `<span code='notranslate'>...</span>` UNLESS the `%{ ... }` appears within an HTML tag.  For example, this:

```
"Or %{register_text} for a new account by <a href='%{path}'>clicking here</a>."
```

needs to become this

```
"Or <span code='notranslate'>%{register_text}</span> for a new account by <a href='%{path}'>clicking here</a>."
```

my current regex doesn't take into account the HTML tag situation:

```
x.gsub(/[?<!]%\{([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]*)\}[?>!]/i) {|s| "<span class='notranslate'>#{s}</span>"}
```

so I am wondering how to do this in Ruby with regex.

Any takers?

Comment: Is there Javascript in the input string? I mean embedded JS specifically.

Comment: You might be better off with an xpath expression than a regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about the input space, so this is the best that I can come up with. I also clean up the regex a bit along the way.

```
/%\{[\w-]+\}(?![^<>]>)/
```

For a well-formed HTML, it will only match tokens that are outside tag. If the HTML is malformed, I don't think I'm up to the task to write the regex.

I also assume that there is no embedded Javascript in the page, since `>` and `<` in Javascript is not escaped.

Comment: Ok - I had to make a small modification to escape the {}: `/\%{([\w-]*)\}(?![^<>]*>)/` but Im getting an odd **warning: regexp has invalid interval** message in ruby.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Is it necessary? It works fine on rubular, though. The invalid message is most likely due to the `-`, can you try escaping it `\-`?

Comment: The hyphen in `[\w-]` is fine. "Interval" probably refers to a `{min,max}` quantifier.  I would escape both braces: `%\{([\w-]*)\}` - or at least the first one: `%\{([\w-]*)}`

Comment: @JoshL: I have edited my answer so that it removes all warnings.

Comment: <a href='%{path}' alt='< back'> <- broken and well formed

Comment: @pguardiario: I expect that my solution breaks on many levels. This is just a patchy solution, and I hope the OP only use this as one-time solution. And although possible, it is quite rare to see `<` and `>` in the attributes, except for inline JS.